# Eclipse does not open on mac

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I recently downloaded the ADT bundle (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) for mac. At first, I was able to open eclipse but every time i created a new project it froze and the force quit itself. After trying a number of fixes an failing I decided to uninstall everything and start over. I Java from my computer and the bundle and re-acquired both.

I re-downloaded java (the newest, v 7) and the bundle (eclipse + plugin) and afterwards things were even worse. I can no longer open eclipse. If I click on the icon nothing happens. It does not show up in the dock, and it does not start and crash, just, nothing happens.

I am on OS X 10.8.4

Does you have any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Try a clean start with the below arguments
./eclipse -clean -refresh  -vmargs -XstartOnFirstThread

from inside eclipse.app

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear to see the cause of the problem but perhaps you may want to go through the process of elimination.

- Check that your Java installation is working through some terminal
  commands.
- See if an Eclipse installation works by itself (from
  eclipse.org, not the ADT Bundle)
- If the above works try to install
  ADT through the Eclipse "Install New Software" feature, and if this
  is where it breaks then perhaps try to obtain a previous version of
  ADT and see if that works)

Comment: Eclipse (not the bundle) has the same behavior - nothing happens when I click it. How can i check if the Java Installation is working?

Comment: open a Terminal and enter "java -version" (without quotes) - this should show the currently installed java version